# Scipy: Can you incorporate exponential weighting into distribution fitting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy, distribution

Given some time series data:

```
np.random.seed(123)
r = pd.Series(np.random.beta(a=0.5, b=0.5, size=1000),
              index=pd.date_range('2013', periods=1000))
```

and the distributions within `scipy.stats._continuous_distns._distn_names`:

```
import scipy.stats as scs
dists = scs._continuous_distns._distn_names
```

I would like to be able to establish a new distribution, and then call it's `.ppf` (percent point function), while incorporating exponential weights into the building of the distribution.

For example, with a [normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) distribution, this would just entail estimating an exponentially-weighted mean and standard deviation:

> All continuous distributions take loc and scale as keyword parameters
>   to adjust the location and scale of the distribution, e.g. for the
>   standard normal distribution the location is the mean and the scale is
>   the standard deviation. [[source]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#shifting-and-scaling)

```
ewm = r.ewm(span=60)
loc = ewm.mean().iloc[-1]
scale = ewm.std().iloc[-1]
print(scs.norm.ppf(q=0.05, loc=loc, scale=scale))
-0.196734019969
```

But I would like to be able to extend this to the broader family of continuous distributions where other parameters (`shape`) are often involved.  For instance,

- [johnsonsu](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.johnsonsu.html) has parameters `a`, `b`, `loc`, `scale`;
- [bradford](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.bradford.html) has parameters `c`, `loc`, `scale`;
- [burr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.burr.html) has parameters `c`, `d`, `loc`, `scale`.

How could I extend this process to [distributions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#continuous-distributions) that have parameters besides `loc` and `scale`?

Combined snippets from above:

```
import scipy.stats as scs
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(123)
r = pd.Series(np.random.beta(a=0.5, b=0.5, size=1000),
              index=pd.date_range('2013', periods=1000))
ewm = r.ewm(span=60)
loc = ewm.mean().iloc[-1]
scale = ewm.std().iloc[-1]
print(scs.norm.ppf(q=0.05, loc=loc, scale=scale))
# -0.196734019969
```

Comment: Are you just looking to estimate lambda?

Comment: Ok, but all of those parameters can be calculated with mean and variance, so it would just require you to run those calculations

Comment: I think it would help to first give a clear mathematical formulation of the problem. *Then* figure out how to implement it.  The question *"Is it possible to use the distributions' .fit method to estimate parameters, that in some way incorporates exponential weightings?"* seems too vague.

Comment: short answer: You need to rewrite the distribution `fit` function to allow for weights. There are currently no weights allowed and all observations are treated as independently and identically distributed observations coming from the given distribution. (i.e. weighted MLE not just weighted method of moments to compute the shape parameters)

Comment: @user333700 Do you think my answer below at least somewhat mimics that approach? (Granted, the bootstrapping I'm using is an intermediate step that wouldn't happen in your approach.)

Comment: Yes, it has the same structure (I guess it has the same large sample properties but different small sample properties, with maybe some small sample bias correction if the parameters estimates are the mean of the bootstrap samples.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my implementation:

- Given an empirical distribution `x`, assign exponential weights to each `x`.
- Use these weights to bootstrap sample a new distribution.  The weights are the `p` parameter to `np.random.choice`.
- The `.fit` method of any distribution can then be called on that bootstrapped data.

### Code:

```
def ewm_weights(i, alpha):
    w = (1 - alpha) ** np.arange(i)[::-1]
    w /= w.sum()
    return w

def bootstrap(a, alpha, size=None):
    p = ewm_weights(i=len(a), alpha=alpha)
    return np.random.choice(a=a, size=size, p=p)
```

The definition of `ewm_weights` follows:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#exponentially-weighted-windows

with `adjust=True`.

### Example:

```
# Create a nonstationary `x` variable with larger mean and stdev in period 2
x1 = np.random.normal(loc=4, scale=3, size=1000)
x2 = np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=5, size=1000)
x = np.hstack((x1,x2))
```

The histogram of `x` looks like this:

```
plt.hist(x, bins=25)
```

[image]

While a bootstrapped `b` with `alpha=0.03` looks like:

```
b = bootstrap(x, alpha=0.03, size=int(1e6))
plt.hist(b, bins=25)
```

[image]

Any continuous distribution from `scipy.stats._continuous_distns._distn_names` can then be fit to `b`.

### Issues:

- A softmax function might make `ewm_weights` safer.
- This approach ignores autocorrelation in `x`.